# Displaying tab content using the Android support library?

Tags: android, tabs

I'll preface this question by admitting that I am brand new to Android programming. I've searched numerous times for the answer -- and it's probable that I'm just not framing my question(s) correctly -- but I cannot seem to figure out how to get my tab contents to work:

I'm targeting sdk 14 but setting sdk 10 as minSDK (I'm still on Gingerbread), so I'm using the v4 support library.

I have my tabs behaving as they should, and I can tell when a particular tab has been selected:

```
private void updateTab (String tabId, int placeholder)
{
    if (tabId.equals(TAB_ROUNDS)) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "tabId: "+tabId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

When R.id.tab_rounds is selected, the Toast shows (same with other tabs: I only included one for brevity). The thing is, I don't know what to do now, and I can't seem to figure out where/how to look.

There's also the very strong possibility that the fragments I'm trying to load into my tabs haven't been properly constructed, but I'm basing them on other content gleaned from various web searches in an attempt to figure out just what I'm doing.

TL;DR: What do I need to do to display the relevant fragments as content for a particular tab? I would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Android.

I don't know which are you using, but i would suggest Action Bar agains TabHost, the first has now become standard in [Android Design](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html).

Eithey way, have you read [Android Developer's API Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)? It's even better from the last time I read it, and it's a great way to get started. Also, you also have samples when you download the SDK for a specific version.

Also, you are thinking to develop to Gingerbread, have a look to [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) and [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/). They are great API's that augment the support library in older versions of Android.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I downloaded ActionBarSherlock, but I'm a freaking idiot because I can't figure out how to set it up for use. I watched the video posted on actionbarsherlock.com, but my setup (Eclipse 4.2.1 and ADT 21) doesn't look like that presented in the video: I don't have an option to create an "Android Project." I have Android Activity Project or Android Library and maybe a few other things, but no plain ol' Android project. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I'm new to Eclipse, too :(

Comment: Don't insult yourself, no need.
About the video, is this [one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GJ6yY1lNNY)?
Instead of creating a new project, try to import it through File->Import/Export->Existing sources